# log4net AdoNetAppender not logging into sql azure db in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, log4net, azure-sql-database

I have been attempting to get log4net logging any info or error into my SQL Azure db in my asp.net web application with no success or any noticable errors. I am attempting to use the ADONetAppender appender with the following web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
         type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"
         />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data,
 Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="Server=;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) 
 VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />

      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

....

In my global.asax Application_Start I call

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Code that runs on application startup
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();


            }
```

Then to attempt to log:

```
 readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_logger.IsInfoEnabled)
            _logger.Info("Performance sensitive Info message");
        _logger.Info("testing web role into Poqlogging");
        _logger.Error("new error",new Exception("new exception"));
    }
```

All of this does nothing as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information you provided above several things could go wrong. To better understand the problem more Info needed.

I can provide a few check points which you can verify:

1. where do you run this application? In compute emulator or on Windows Azure
2. IF it is running into Compute Emulator have your setup firewall at SQL Azure to accept connection from your development machine and vice-versa if required.
3. If this application is running in Windows Azure, have you modified the firewall policy
4. Where ever you run this application, you must be able to prove first that a connection to SQL Azure is possible because application itself can not do this, you would have to setup the environment so connection to SQL Azure is working
5. With Log4Net I always do two things:

   1. I always verify first that my Log4Net setting/code does work file using the local logging
   2. Once above is confirmed, I jump to next step and add code/configuration to change logging to other destination.
6. If all of above are verified, then look for network trace where your application is running (compute Emulator or Windows Azure) for any network data towards SQL Azure server.

Comment: Windows Azure SQL Database (formerly SQL Azure) Connection 
         String Example
        The following example shows a connection string for SQL Database 
       (formerly SQL Azure).

     <add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data 
        Source=tcp:ServerName.database.windows.net,1433;Initial 
        Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User 
 Id=username@servername;Password=password;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" /> // the TCP and The Port giving the trouble

Answer (score 4):

Using log4net and SQL Azure is a great way to perform application logging in Azure.  Here are some things to try:

1) Your connection string should look like this:

```
<connectionString value="data source=ServerName;initial catalog=DBName;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=SQLUsername;Password=SQLPassword" />
```

2) The applog4net.Internal.Debug key should go in the appSettings section of your web.config, not the log4net section. e.g.

```
...
</configSections>
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
<log4net>
...
```

3) log4net internal debug messages are written to the System.Diagnostics.Trace system.  When troubleshooting log4net configuration problems, I like to redirect the trace output to a file by adding the following to my web.config (note that you have to ensure that your ASP.Net server process can write to the file):

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add
        name="textWriterTraceListener"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="c:\temp\log4net.txt" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: tried everything, i published the website onto azure, still i couldn't get it inserting logging information into sql azure.

Comment: Were you able to generate the internal debugging trace file?  The trace file will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: it's not generating any files when i run on my emulator. nor does on the Azure

Comment: Like @Avkash said, first get log4net logging locally to a file, debug console, etc.  THEN you can troubleshoot your SQL Azure ADONetAppender  specific problems.

Comment: well, the file appender can write files to local c drive. but the tracer doesn't work. I have no problem connecting to Azure. I was able to write the website and generate log file on my local machine, but once i deployed to the Azure, it's not doing anything

Comment: Is log4net's internal debugging enabled?  If so, you'll want to configure your ADONetAppender to log to SQL Azure, making sure that you're logging to the file appender as well.  The log file produced by the file appender will give you the exact error that occurred when trying to log to SQL Azure.

Answer (score 2):

And I agree; the AdoNetAppender works when the connection is specified as in Answer #2 above. Also, if you are remote from the Azure SQL database, be sure to create a firewall source IP rule to allow your IP address to connection to the Azure SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

In my quest to resolve this, I discovered that an Azure SQL table **MUST** have a **CLUSTERED INDEX**. Based on the standard log table, this is how it should look.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log] (
[Id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Thread] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
[Level] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
[Logger] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
[Message] [varchar] (4000) NOT NULL,
[Exception] [varchar] (2000) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

seem like you need to write a custom appender to do the job

http://cloudshaper.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/logging-with-log4net-on-the-azure-platform/

Comment: Actually, you don't need to create your own appender if you're logging to SQL Azure.  The built-in ADONetAppender works out of the box.